# What is the use of build.prop.bakforspec and vendor.prop?

Tags: settings, ota-update

I have been editing build.prop without rooting the device(via adb mechanism by temporarily flashing twrp recovery using fastboot).
And whenever an OTA update comes, it resets my buildprop.
If I reflect the same changes in build.prop.bakforspec , will my changes be secure of will they be reset again?
And why are these files there:
build.prop.bakforspec,
default.prop
vendor.prop
power.prop?

Comment: An alternative approach would be using an "init script" (a script that's run at boot time with root permissions), and apply your changes via `setprop`. I have not played with that, and it requires your device supporting `init.d` (or adding that via an app, or maybe even Tasker's on-boot event could deal with that), but it might be worth a try. Even if that script should not survive an OTA, you then could simply "copy it back" afterwards.

Comment: Oh! Thanks, I didn't know about that. Although I don't really know what's the use of all these 3 scripts and when are these loaded while device startup. But as you said it's alternative can be init script, I can relate it more or less.

Comment: I didn't make that an answer as you especially asked for details on each of the files, which I cannot answer for sure or even not at all (never heard of that bakforspec, which might be specific to that ROM or manufacturer or forgotten from development even, or of that `power.prop` – and am not sure for the order of processing either). My guess would be `default.prop` being run first to set some defaults (as it [resides in the boot image](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=67401292&postcount=2)), then `build.prop`, then the vendor specific settings.

Comment: Right. That makes sense. Thankyou :)